# What is the "kube-node-lease" namespace for?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-namespace

I know the purpose of other Kubernetes default namespaces such as: `kube-system`, `default` & `kube-public`, but there is no official document about the `kube-node-lease`.

The only [official explanation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#heartbeats) I've found is:

> Heartbeats, sent by Kubernetes nodes, help determine the availability of a node. There are two forms of heartbeats: updates of NodeStatus and the [Lease object](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#lease-v1-coordination-k8s-io). Each Node has an associated Lease object in the kube-node-lease namespace.

With `kubectl get all -n kube-node-lease` I'm getting no resources at all. (*k8s-version: 1.15*)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

here is the **Kubernetes Enhancement Proposal** of  [node-heartbeat.md](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/tree/master/keps/sig-node/589-efficient-node-heartbeats) for this feature. It makes node heartbeats significantly cheaper from both scalability and performance perspective.

This introduce a new Lease built-in API in the newly created API group `coordination.k8s.io.` which makes it easily reusable for other purposes [3rd party device monitoring plugins](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/606) that's why it is  namespaced.

This feature become stable in  [k8s 1.17](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/12/09/kubernetes-1-17-release-announcement/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) One thing bothers me though. It says status is implemented, but PR is closed and it's not part of K8s yet?

Comment: its stable in k8s 1.17 . before it was in beta phase

Comment: node-heartbeat.md file no longer exists, last existed in https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/0460fcf4637d440ce7d539a931e44dae931f9849/keps/sig-node/0009-node-heartbeat.md , moved/deleted in https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/commit/7eef794bb549a50c6b08c457556ff0eac98a4c6b

Comment: A permalink to the (02/2022) version - https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/761668f82fef6727d2cbee10e632c371dfded529/keps/sig-node/589-efficient-node-heartbeats/README.md

Comment: Thanks @GabiDavar I added a working link.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new explanation in the official Kubernetes [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/) about Namespaces:

> `kube-node-lease` This namespace holds [Lease](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/cluster-resources/lease-v1/) objects associated with each node. Node leases allow the kubelet to send [heartbeats](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#heartbeats) so that the control plane can detect node failure.